# Azure AD Error Code 90094

Tags: azure

I have an Excel plugin, which uses Azure AD (ADAL) for authentication. I have made a second copy of the app and the needed changes in Azure AD. All user can use the first app. The second app I am the only one who can log in. They have the same rights like in the first app. What Azure give as error on login is:

Error Code: 90094

Error reason: Other

I cannot find information for this error. What is returned to the user is "Admin have to give privileges to this app". But the privileges are given. The same like in the first app.

Do you have any information for this error code?

P.S. What I found is, that this is connected with required permissions from the app. If I add a user, who is a Global Administrator in Azure AD, after logon comes a window "The app needs permission to: ...  (Accept, Cancel)" and after that, he can use the app, even if he is changed to normal user. If the user is normal Azure AD user, this windows does not appear and he is rejected with the error 90094. The same happens with a user, who is Limited Administrator and it does not matter what for admin role he has.

P.S. 2

On my support request, Microsoft support did not tell me what this error means  ("This is a custom application and there is no info about this error. There would be info if this was an enterprise application").

After deleting the app registration and make it again, there is no more such a problem. And I cannot reproduce it (I have tried hard :) ). And if you give me an answer, I cannot prove it. So you can look on this question as closed.

Comment: I have run into a case like this where the ability for users to grant programs privileges was removed globally in Azure AD. Since they already accepted the first program they are fine but cannot accept any other ones. Can a new user access the first program?

Comment: I had similar experience in my last project - this had happens about 3 times for  us, and one of cases was sort of similar with your one and affected production customers - no one was able to log-in app. In all cases there were similarities:
1)When things got broken - it got broken for dev, production, CI environments (we had different apps for each configured the same way)
2)App recreation solves the problem
3)The problem usually happens when MS adds new permission scopes for app
4) Usually problem only affecting single permission scope

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where the error occurred if anybody other than a Global Administrator was the one that created the AAD app registration. It came down to a subtle difference in the way Azure AD sets permissions for the application based on who sets the application permissions in the old Management Portal. I don't know if they have this problem in the new Resource Manager portal, or if it's even the same case as what you're encountering without more information.

Comment: This was not an answer which can help me and I do not understand why StackOverflow give you points.  Igor B comment was better than this one.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1d64db4-06a4-43b8-ac32-292ccb8bfff0/active-directory-authentication-you-cant-access-this-application-granting-consent?forum=WindowsAzureAD):

> As an administrator, you can also consent to an application's delegated permissions on behalf of all the users in your tenant. This will prevent the consent dialog from appearing for every user in the tenant. You can do this from the Azure portal from your application page. From the Settings blade for your application, click Required Permissions and click on the Grant Permissions button.

[image: Required permissions]

This worked for me.